# why ng-model initial value not get displayed

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular JS. Here is my html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>My App</title>
        <script src = "angular.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="index">
            {{message}}
        </div>

        <form>
            First Name:<br>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.username">{{user.username}}<br>
            Last Name:<br>
            <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
        </form>

        <script src = "app.js"></script>
        <script src = "credentials.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Then I want to initialize some data for username and password :

```
(function(){
    var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
    app.controller("index", ["$scope", function($scope){
        $scope.message="Hello, it's me!";
        $scope.user={
            username: "admin",
            password: "admin"
        };      
    }]);
})();
```

The username and password doesn't get displayed. Why?

Comment: Could you give us a full html template?

Comment: Did you attach the `ng-app` and `ng-controller` directives to the HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller div is not covering the area where you have user object. controller div must include the code in which you are accessing  user object

You can change the code like this

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="index">
            {{message}}


        <form>
            First Name:<br>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.username">{{user.username}}<br>
            Last Name:<br>
            <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
        </form>
 </div>
        <script src = "app.js"></script>
        <script src = "credentials.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: I have  included `angular.js` in the html `<head>` section.

Answer (score 3):

You're problem is that you have bound the controller to the div-tag surrounding the `{{message}}` expression and not the whole block containing the form. If bind your controller to a surrounding element youre code will work as expected.

Here's one way to do this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="index">
        <div>
            {{message}}
        </div>

        <form>
            First Name:<br>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.username">{{user.username}}<br>
            Last Name:<br>
            <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-app="">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
    <p ng-bind="name"></p>
</div>
```

as you can see in this example

> ng-model directive binds the value of HTML controls (input, select,
>   textarea) to application data. ng-bind directive binds application
>   data to the HTML view.

i can see ng-model in your code but there is not ng-bind which actually binds data to your view. probably that is the reason why your code is not displaying username and password.

Comment: In my case, I want to make the inputs with some defaults values filled. But, I would like to avoid using `ng-init="value here"`.

Answer (score 1):

With the ng-model directive you can bind the value of an input field to a variable created in AngularJS.

You can use the ng-bind directive, which will bind the innerHTML of the element to the specified model property:

ng-model for input elements like input, textarea and ng-bind for h1,label etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-controller="index" ng-app="myApp">
  <form>
    First Name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.username">
    <br> Last Name:
    <br>
    <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
  app.controller("index", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
      username: "admin",
      password: "admin"
    };
  }]);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As,Venu prasad H S and domyos already suggested , a reply to the comment of M. Ko as i don't have enough reputation to comment,

You have defined the ng-model out of the scope of the controller,

```
<div ng-controller="index">
            {{message}}
 </div>
```

What this does is that your controller can access only the stuff inside this div only, as many others suggested you can put an entire div in the body you can do

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="index">
    <div>
        {{message}}
    </div>

    <form>
        First Name:<br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.username">{{user.username}}<br>
        Last Name:<br>
        <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
    </form>
</div>
```

As very aptly provided by domyos , now what this does is that your controller can get to your form and you can display the values you desire.

Alternatively you can also but your controller in the body tag with your ng-app

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="index">
```

but it is recommended that you put it inside a div, you want to do this so that you can have multiple controllers in one module i.e. on ng-app.

Also, try to name controller as "indexCtrl" as in IndexController it is just a naming convention but that makes your code more readable.
Hope you find this information useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-app` and `ng-controller` directives in your HTML page.

Here is link of Plunker for the same.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/v1cgRk0yMw3ubfFXvieX?p=info)

And donot forget to give reference

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```